# openai-gym how to determine what the values in observation space mean

Tags: python, openai-gym

Is there any documentation where I could details regarding this kind of stuff?
For example:

```
import gym

# environment for agent
env = gym.make('Pendulum-v0')
env.reset()

print(env.observation_space.high, env.observation_space.low)

# pendulum observation space ranges from [-1, -1, -8] to [1, 1, 8]
```

I cant figure out what each number in observation space means. I guess two of them are x and y coordinates (although I dont know which is which), and what does the third number stand for?

Comment: Had you already found http://gym.openai.com/docs/#spaces ?

Comment: @AMC, yes I found that. I was hoping there would be something more detailed. I guess best way is to check github page for each environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently `openai`'s github page has a wiki which contains the information I was looking for: https://github.com/openai/gym/wiki

Answer (score 0):

Open AI's documentation covers this:

1. Dimensionality of Observation space, Action space, reward, etc. of all the environments:
   https://github.com/openai/gym/wiki/Table-of-environments
2. Specific ranges for them, e.g.
   https://github.com/openai/gym/wiki/Pendulum-v1

In your case, assuming Pendulum-v0 shares v1's features, your three values mean:

- cos(theta), between -1 and 1
- sin(theta), between -1 and 1
- theta dot, or angular velocity, between -8 and 8

Best